# How can I overload the CSS from a redirect Web Page

Tags: c#, html, css, webview

I have make a redirect on a Website and now i don't know how i can overload/override the css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=example.com" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
```

```
 private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
            string src = "ms-appx-web:///Assets/MyHTMLPage.html";
            this.MainWebView.Navigate(new Uri(src));
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more ?

Comment: I have a CSS on the Web page and a CSS in Visual Studio. Now i would overload the CSS from the Web page with my CSS in Visual Studio. The website has a redirect on http://example.com and this have the Styles from example.css and i would overload or override it with main.css from Visual studio. Maybe you can help me now better. When not can you ask me what you not understand.

Comment: ok. so basically, you want to use your own style on the redirected page ignoring the redirected page's CSS ? Right ?

Comment: you want to use your own style on the redirected page ignoring the redirected page's CSS ? Right ? If this is the case then I think you cannot override CSS on the redirected page.

Comment: hmm okei can i ignore the redirected css?

Comment: Nopes, as far as I know. But lets see what others have to say.

Comment: I have a Mobile App on this App i have a Webview. I redirected the Webpage on the Webview and it isn't possible to edit the style of the Web page in the Webview? Are you sure?